# Powershell error output supression (again)

Tags: error-handling, azure-powershell

I know this has been asked more than once before - because I've searched and read them all!..

Despite that, I am fighting a particularly obstinate powershell error that seemingly just will not let me suppress outputting great wodges of red to the screen. I'm doing a simple connection to the AzureAD module with this one-liner...

```
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
```

Note that I work in the Azure tenants of many different customers, some enforce 2FA, some do not. I'm writing a bunch of helper functions to ease the day-to-day grind of logging on and off many times to different tenants... 
I know that cmdlet will fail when attempting to connect to a 2FA-enforced tenant... I expect it, and I want to trap it (silently) and handle that error myself. most of which I can do, but its the 'silently' bit that is particularly troublesome. I've tried every possible method of suppressing output that I know about (mostly from the other articles on here!). 
With no countermeasures taken at all, that cmdlet generates 6 (six!) error events, all of which show onscreen. Using any of the supression methods I can think of, I can suppress 5 of those, but no matter what I try, one error always still appears onscreen... I have tried:

```
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential *> .errors.txt
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential *>&1 > .errors.txt
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential *>&1 | out-null
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential 2>&1 | out-null
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential *>$null
$void=Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
$void=Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential >$null
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential|out-null
[void](Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential)
```

So far, absolutely nothing works to completely suppress all of the error output, - I always get that last 1 error ruining my tidy screen output.

I've also checked if the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet has any options such as -quiet or -silent etc. - it does not..

FYI, the actual error thrown is:

```
Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by 
your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you
must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
Trace ID: 73e00fc9-6e7b-4210-8aa6-285b04692800
Correlation ID: 1b9e2d49-1ed6-4f1e-8ce9-65761a15edd9
Timestamp: 2020-02-14 16:12:10Z
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential *> .errors.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD
```

Does anyone have any ideas for a nuclear strength option to completely suppress absolutely all output from errors? My catch block does work to trap the `[Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException]` named exception, so I can deal with the error just fine, but I really want to not have that splodge of red error text 'corrupting' my output.

TIA!

Paul G.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to wrap most AzureAD code with try{}catch{}. A quick test seems to work for your case:

```
try {
    Connect-AzureAD -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Error -Message "Login cancelled or something..."
}
```

Hope you find this useful.